# Retrieving page post public shares collection via graph api, from pages and people profiles

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

## Introduction

I am using *Graph API Explorer* for exploring requests and responses, via an app and a system user *(SU)* in a business manager *(BM)* making graph public posts requests for a page owned by the same BM.

SU has Page Analyst role.

The available environment API version is `2.11`.

I expect to collect people and page names who share in public an allotment of posts create by page editors.

## Core question

When starting sequence, at first I use a user access token. When I make requests to `/me/accounts`, I am able to get a page access token *(PAT)* for the page of my interest.

Switching to PAT in API Explorer, `/me/posts` returns all recent page posts, so the token seems valid for next requests.

Indeed, I am successfully able to get page post collection for common edges using patterns like `PAGEID_POSTID/reactions` and `PAGEID_POSTID/comments`.

I am going nuts for `PAGEID_POSTID/sharedposts` edge, since I am only able to see post shares details done from foreign pages, even there are people who shared it in public.

### Example

For a page post I focused on, there are 11 shares.

*public / private visibility*

- 10 shares are public
- 1 share is private

*user / page profiles*

- 8 shares are done form user profiles
- 3 shares are done from page profiles

As a regular facebook user, you would see 10 shares using a web browser.

Calling the sharedposts API edge as above, I just see only the shares from page profiles.

I expect to get a 10 public shares collection.

Comment: You can only get user posts, after the user logged in to your app and granted it permission. As long as that is not the case, those shares will simply be invisible to your app.

Comment: Thanks.

Since official reference doesnt clear it, I was hoping for a different behavior for `sharedposts` calls performed with page access token.

So, for what concerns graph API, these user shares are anyway user posts, needing `user_posts` authorization to be granted to the app, I suppose.

Comment: Dug on facebook bug tracking platform about this: this is the standard expected behavior since graph API 2.4, according to facebook representatives' replyes
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/191104101236614/?comment_id=1079680802096737
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/824627191037021/?comment_id=829459243887149
(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻